# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number laravel en el updae

Tags: php, laravel

```
    $productos_id = Productos::select('id_productos')->pluck('id_productos');
        
        
        for($count = 0; $count < count($productos_id); $count++){
           

            $cantidadproducto=Productos::find($productos_id[$count])->pluck('cantidad_disponible');
            
            Productos::find($productos_id[$count])->update([
               
                'cantidad_disponible'=>$request->cantidadComprada + $cantidadproducto
              ]);
            
    }
```

intento capturar el id_productos correspondiente y pasarlo a mi funcion update entre ello capturo la cantidad_disponible para actualizar el campo cantidad_disponible
lo que deberia hacer el for es filtrar dependiendo del id seleccionado, hasta ahora me muestra ambos productos
es como puedo acceder a mi variable productos id tambien desde un array de id_producto

```
            foreach(session ('productos_add') as $key=>$Producto){

            $data2 = array(
               
                'productos_id'=>$Producto['id_producto'],
                
              );
    
        $insert_schedule1[] = $data2;
    
            }
        dd($insert_schedule1);
```

Comment: Creo que llevas 3 preguntas del mismo estilo para lo mismo, y creo que es porque no sabes depurar el código para averiguarlo por ti mismo. En PHP puro, para ver lo que contiene una variable, se puede usar `var_dump($variable);` o bien `print_r($variable)`, y deberia funcionarte aunque estes usand Laravel, que tambien creo que usa una función propia llamada `dd` para lo mismo. Léete [este artículo](https://edinsoncs.com/diferencias-dd-vs-dump-vs-var_dump-vs-print_r.html) y aprende su uso, porque realmente lo necesitas para ir descubriendo en cada asignacion que haces los datos que realmente hay

Comment: ¿Revisaste que devuelve el método [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#retrieving-a-list-of-column-values)?

Comment: si dos numeros 12 y el 13 correspondientes al  id_productos

Comment: Pues si devuelve dos números seguramente eso es un array, y dudo que la siguiente sentencia lo soporte. Los arrays se recorren en bucles normalmente, y no lo estas haciendo. Usa foreach() para ello y dentro del bucle pones el resto de lineas cambiando el $productos_id por lo que hayas definido en el bucle. Busca documentación sobre `foreach()` para entenderlo.

Comment: @LuisFelipeBarrosBustos ¿Ese cambio que has realizado en tu última edición ya ha solucionado tu pregunta?  ¿O hay algun nuevo error?

Comment: un nuevo error resulta que me muestra ambos productos, quiero que filtre uno solo dependiendo del id seleccionado

Comment: Pero entonces para que consultas a la base de datos todos?  Deberias consultar tan solo el "seleccionado" tal como dices agregando un `->where` a la consulta y luego ya no te haria falta el `for` porque obtendrias un resultado único.  ¿Ese "seleccionado" como lo recoges?  ¿Por post?

Comment: diste en el punto, nose como recogerlo lo que si se esta en una session carrito pero tengo mas de un elemento en el carrito

Comment: Estará en algun POST o REQUEST... haz un `print_r($_POST)` o `dd($_POST)` o lo mismo con `$_REQUEST` a ver si lo ves... y si no lo ves prueba lo mismo con `$_SESSION`... en alguna parte tiene que estar.. no se si se podra hacer un `dd($request->session())` tambien... (no se laravel y ahi poco te puedo ayudar)

Comment: esta  en el array de la sesion id_producto, pero aquella generalmente tiene mas de 1 elemento